# Bootstrap Scrollspy doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

Why my scrollspy doesn't work?

http://jsfiddle.net/NnREW/

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
         <li><a href="#test">test</a></li>
         <li><a href="#test2">test2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give your css for html element via class not id. This make simpler your thing.
I think your css includes more than needed thing.
In addition to, you have to add bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap-combined.min.css.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="nav" class="span3">
            <ul class="nav nav-list affix">
                <li><a href="#test">test</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#test2">test2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="span9 content">
            <div id="test">My first div</div>
            <div id="test2">My second div</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content div {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 600px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NnREW/40/)